# Is there a way to make a folder you CAN'T share images from?

Tags: folder-organizer

I'm constantly scared I might accidentally "butt-dial" share my girlfriend's sensitive images, is there any way to make a folder for images that won't include a share function?

Comment: Creating a .nomedia file with any file explorer hides the folder, in which images are stored . Try that and see if your "share" apps can access it or not (I guess they shouldn't but to be sure) pr use one of the many apps on Play Store that  hide photos and test